# How do I define a filetype plugin for git commits in Neovim?

Tags: git, vim, neovim

I want to set `textwidth=72` when I'm editing a git commit. How do I load a git commit ftplugin in Neovim? I've tried defining the `ftplugin/gitcommit.lua` file, but it has no effect. (Other ftplugins in the same folder work as expected.)

Comment: What's `:set filetype?` if you don't do anything and are editing a commit message? As far as I can remember I get the behavior you want out of the box. Maybe you are actively overriding it already somewhere else.

Comment: Also try `:verbose set textwidth?`

Answer (score 4):

I had this in my older Vim configuration:

```
au BufRead */COMMIT_EDITMSG set filetype=markdown tw=72
```

Using lua, that would look something like this:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufEnter" }, {
  pattern = {
    "*/COMMIT_EDITMSG",
  },
  command = "set filetype=markdown tw=72",
})
```

...although with my current configuration this isn't necessary, and I can populate `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/gitcommita.lua` like this:

```
vim.o.textwidth = 72
vim.o.filetype = "markdown"
```

And it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `git` ftplugin **already** sets `:help 'textwidth'` to the desired value so there is no point whatsoever in trying to do it on your own.

Just make sure filetype detection and plugins are enabled by putting this in your `vimrc` or whatever is the Neovim equivalent:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're setting the `EDITOR` or `GIT_EDITOR` variable correctly! I was defining `ftplugin` config for Neovim but `git` was using the system Vim. Pointing to the correct Vim executable resolved my issue.